# define R objects in a list based on column names in a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, construct, coerce

I have a data frame `df` with column names `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, etc.

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100), x2=rnorm(100),x3=rnorm(100))
```

I would like to create an R object that is a list that looks like:

```
my.list <- list(y, N = length(y),
                x1 = x1,
                x2 = x2,
                ...
                )
```

Where `x1` -> `xn` are the colums of `df`.

Comment: you mean `as.list(df)` or am I misunderstanding your desired output?

Comment: @EricFail I do, thanks that should have been obvious.

Comment: Or `c(df)`.  Fore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post it here so that the question can be marked as answered,

```
dfL <- as.list(df)
str(dfL)
#> List of 3
#>  $ x1: num [1:100] -0.0793 0.3049 -1.2734 -1.9316 -0.361 ...
#>  $ x2: num [1:100] -0.302 0.277 1.131 -0.295 0.828 ...
#>  $ x3: num [1:100] 0.486 1.73 -0.13 0.943 0.663 ...
```

or

```
require(dplyr)
dfL <- df %>% as.list()
```

or the minimal option, [as suggested by Rich Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753076/define-r-objects-in-a-list-based-on-column-names-in-a-dataframe/48753196#comment84507012_48753076),

```
dfL <- c(df)
```